# Android Change Height of Listview Items

Tags: android, listview, size

I have a ListView object in Android that contains objects which have toStrings that write 4 lines of text.

Currently, the ListView defaults to only showing 2 lines of text per element instead of the wanted 4.

I've been looking over google and stackexchange and most of the questions like this have been creating custom XML's and dynamically changing the height of the items in the Listview based on some external parameters.

Before I go to the trouble of making custom XML am I perchance overlooking some stupidly easy means of just changing the listView so that it displays 4 lines instead of 2 lines of text for each element in the listView?

Comment: **"...write 4 lines of text."** : How? Are you using a single `TextView` set to multi-line?

Comment: I'm using literally the default listView with no changes to the TextView object.

Comment: So what do you actually want? A single multi-line `TextView` (but bigger obviously)? Or multiple `TextViews`? Either way you're going to have to create your own list item layout file.

Comment: I was hoping for a single ListView that contained multiple TextViews that would be tall enough to display 4 lines of text ecah instead of 2 lines of text.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually found this resource to be very helpful:

http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/

Since I was using the simple_list_item_single_choice as an argument to my adapter, I simply found the source for it on Android's github and copied it into a custom_list_view.xml.

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_single_choice.xml

And changed

```
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall
```

To

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Then I called

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_text_view, connections);
```

Hope this helps future google users who were as frustrated as I was.

Answer (score 0):

Think your stuck making a custom xml file.  Shouldn't be to much work for just a slightly larger view though.

Comment: Could somebody link me to a good tutorial on how to do this from start to finish?  In particular, alot of tutorials start with "finding simple_layout_1" which I'm not sure where to find.